# OpenCV canonical way to copy into a ROI clipped at the image borders

Tags: c++, opencv

If using something like

```
sourceMat.copyTo(destinationMat(roiRect));
```

with `roiRect` having `sourceMat`s size, it fails if the `roiRect` partially lies outside of `destinationMat`'s borders.

Is there an easy way among the myriads of OpenCV's methods to clip this copy into the valid target area without calculating clipped ROIs for both source and destination matrix?

Comment: not what you asked but roi computation is easy. cv::Rect clippedOrFullROI = srcFullSizeROI & dstFullSizeROI;

Comment: This `clippedOrFullROI` may be smaller that the `srcFullSizeROI` in any direction, so we would need some `clippedOrFullSourceROI` and `clippedOrFullDestROI` I guess?

Comment: does your ROI not start at (0,0)? your sample looked like you always want to ROI the whole image if possible.

Comment: I have ROIs in both source and destination image, and both are of same size. However, any of them may partly lie outsite the source or destination image respectively.

Comment: afaik there is no way  to come around testing boths rois against their image size. then create sub images. and adjust sub image roi if necessary. opencv rect operators make this quite easy to code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use warpAffine and set the transformation matrix to the proper translation. If you want the destination rect to be a different size, then you can add scaling to the transformation.

I use this to make the 2d translation matrix:

```
inline cv::Mat TranslationMat2d(const float dx, const float dy) {
    cv::Mat result = cv::Mat::eye(cv::Size(3, 3), CV_32FC1);
    result.at<float>(2, 0) = dx;
    result.at<float>(2, 1) = dy;
    return result;
}
```

Then use warpAffine something like:

```
warpAffine(srcImage, dstImage, translationMat, imgSize, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, backgroundColor);
```

Comment: That would need all the calculations if clipping accours on source or destination like the method mentioned above. If those calculations are made, the method above would be the easiest way I guess.